Edit value of "domain" tag seen in XML output of "virsh domcapabilities"
How do I change the domain parameter displayed by virsh domcapabilities from qemu to kvm?
<domainCapabilities>
  <path>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</path>
  <domain>qemu</domain>

I want to change the system
so that virsh domcapabilities outputs kvm in the future.

Do you mean that you want to edit the output of virsh domcapabilities, or do you mean that you want to change the system so that virsh domcapabilities outputs kvm in the future?      Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Use an XML-aware tool. Here's one I like
virsh domcapabilities |
xmlstarlet edit --update '//domainCapabilities/domain' --value 'kvm'

Output after closing the domainCapabilities tag so it's legal XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<domainCapabilities>
  <path>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</path>
  <domain>kvm</domain>
</domainCapabilities>

